# Fix number of Items in Datalist ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I want to have fix number of items in datalist and the rest are only displayed if I click on "show more" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .Take(n) when setting the datasource. When they click show more don't use the Take() method